# Integrating velocity field to get position

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, physics

I feel silly for simply being brainstuck, but consider the following integral, physically it would be the solution of $\mathbf{p} = \tfrac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}$ - the  position of a given particle in space with respect to the time and a velocity vector field.

$$\mathbf{p}(x,y) = \int_a^b{\mathbf{v}(x,y)}dt$$

However I have no idea how to describe the $x$ and $y$ components of the velocity vector in t. Or how to convert dt to dx & dy? Say for example $\mathbf{v} = \left \langle 3x, xy  \right \rangle$ Which would result in:

$$\mathbf{p}(x,y) = \int_a^b{3x}dt\cdot\mathbf{i}+\int_a^b{xy}dt\cdot\mathbf{j}$$

Buth how then to continue? I should be possible to calculate this right? I know the speed vector at each point in space, so over a given time period I should be able to get the new position right?

Comment: Looks like you have a velocity field of flow, $\mathbf{v}(x,y)$. But then you should have $\mathbf{p}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial t}$, not $\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}$. Also, $\mathbf p$ is then not a particle position, but acceleration. Anyway, you seem to be working with fluid dynamics, not particle dynamics. Could you tell more precisely what problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be confused because of the notation. If $\mathbb p$ is supposed to be the position, it should depend only on time, not on another position. That means $\mathbb p$ should be a function of one variable.

The differential equation is supposed to be $\frac{d\mathbb p}{dt} = \mathbb v(\mathbb p)$. The integral form is
$$
\mathbb p(t) = \mathbb p(0) + \int_{t_0}^{t} \mathbb v(\mathbb p(s)) ds,
$$
but this generally is not the method to find the solution.

To find $\mathbb p$ given $\mathbb p(0)$ and $\mathbb v$, it may help to break $\mathbb p(t)$ into $\mathbb p(t) = \langle p_x(t), p_y(t) \rangle$ and $\mathbb v(x, y)$ into $\mathbb v(x, y) = \langle v_x(x, y), v_y(x, y) \rangle$. The differential equation for the vector $\mathbb p$ can be written as a system of scalar differential equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dp_x}{dt} & = v_x(p_x, p_y) \\
\frac{dp_y}{dt} & = v_y(p_x, p_y).
\end{align*}

As an example, suppose $\mathbb v(x, y) = \langle 3x, xy \rangle$, *i.e.*, $v_x(x, y) = 3x$ and $v_y(x, y) = xy$. Then you have the system
\begin{align*}
\frac{dp_x}{dt} & = 3p_x \\
\frac{dp_y}{dt} & = p_xp_y.
\end{align*}
The first equation can be solved independently for $p_x$, giving
$$p_x(t) = c_1e^{3t}$$
where $c_1$ is a constant. Substitute this into $p_x$ in the second equation to get
$$
\frac{dp_y}{dt} = c_1e^{3t}p_y.
$$
This equation is separable. The solution is
$$
p_y(t) = c_2e^{\frac{c_1}3 e^{3t}}
$$
where $c_2$ is another constant.

$c_1$ and $c_2$ can be determined once the initial condition is given.
If $\mathbb p(0) = \langle x_0, y_0\rangle$ is given, then
$$
\mathbb p(0) = \langle x_0, y_0\rangle =
\langle c_1, c_2e^{\frac{c_1}3} \rangle.
$$
It is easy to verify that $c_1 = x_0$ and $c_2 = y_0e^{-\frac{x_0}3}$. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb p(t) = \langle x_0e^{3t}, y_0e^{\frac{x_0}3\left(e^{3t} - 1\right)} \rangle
$$

Answer (score 1):

The first relation is wrong, it should be 
$$\mathbf{v}=\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}.\tag{1}$$

Next, the solution is 
$$\mathbf{p}(t)=\mathbf{p}_0+\int_0^t\mathbf{v}(t')dt'$$
where you should known $\mathbf{v}$ as a function of $t$, not as a function of $(x,y)$.

If you have $\mathbf{v}(x,y)$, so you have no need to use an integral representation, but you should solve the pair of differential equation $(1)$ where $\mathbf{p}=(x,y)$, and $x(t), y(t)$ are the unknown functions.